# Ignoring some but not all gestures in nested UITableViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView and each of its cells has another UITableView in it (these child UITableViews scroll horizontally through some images).

All this is working great BUT when a user taps a cell, the tap is only received by the nested child table view.  I would like for a tap to select the parent cell but still allow the user to drag in the child table view.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try to set a delegate to your parent cell from your child tableView ?

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. Was hoping to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a delegate for the child cell to handle the request.  Still hoping for more direct way to handle the touches.